# Android app crashes after rotating from LANDSCAPE to PORTRAIT

Tags: java, android-view

I'm building my first Android app and I've consulted quite some tutorials and stackoverflow posts, but I can't seem to find the proper fix for this problem. 
I've been following YouTube tutorials from TheNewBoston and Derek Banas, as well as some written tutorials.

My app runs as it should when starting the app (being in Portrait mode). When I swap it to landscape, it still works fine. However when I rotate it back to portrait, the app crashes with the following error:

```
04-12 23:42:12.331  28004-28004/nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment, PID: 28004
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment/nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4054)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1314)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4054)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1314)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment.MainPanelFragment did not create a view.
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5020)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4054)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1314)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The actual error being:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment/nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment.MainPanelFragment did not create a view.
```

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int screenOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (screenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            hideSidePanel();
        }
    }

    private void hideSidePanel() {
        View detailPane = findViewById(R.id.detail_panel);
        if(detailPane.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            detailPane.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

MainPanelFragment:

```
public class MainPanelFragment extends ListFragment {

    boolean orientation;
    int currentListViewItem;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> connectArrayToListView = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, API.dummyData);
        setListAdapter(connectArrayToListView);

        orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentListViewItem = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }

        if (orientation) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            showDetails(currentListViewItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_panel, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("curChoice", currentListViewItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        showDetails(position);
        // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    void showDetails(int kaart) {

        currentListViewItem = kaart;

        if (orientation) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(kaart, true);

            DetailPanelFragment details = (DetailPanelFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_panel);

            if (details == null || details.getShowIndex() == -1) {
                details = DetailPanelFragment.newInstance(kaart);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.main_panel, details);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", kaart);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/main_panel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        class="nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment.MainPanelFragment"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/detail_panel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        class="nl.avans.mbd2.android.gideon.van.david.multipanefragment.DetailPanelFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_detail_panel.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Detail panel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/kaartenListViewDetail"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_main_panel.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I also have a folder in `/res` named `layout-land`. It contains an `activity_main.xml` file which is exactly identical to the one posted above. 
I've seen similiar questions like this one but it seems that this situation is not (enough) the same to find a valid answer.

Comment: Remove the super.oncreateView() call within the onCreateView() call in your MainPanelFragment and then can you update what happens?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I tried that but unfortunately exactly the same crash occurs, with the same errors.